# addClass - one function instead of 3 functions (shorten code)

Tags: javascript, yui, addclass, yui3

Apologies I didnt really know how to title this post.

I have the following 3 functions in YUI. What I do is look for a div with classname **.box2**, **.box3**, or **.box4**, and then add another class to all those divs ie the **.box2** div gets another div **.2**

The code below works but I'm too much of a noob to get it all combined into one function for all values of the var **number** instead of writing it out 3 times like this.

```
var number = 2;
var nodes = Y.all(".box"+ number);

nodes.each(function(node){  

    node.addClass(number);

});



var number = 3;
var nodes = Y.all(".box"+ number);

nodes.each(function(node){  

    node.addClass(number);

});



var number = 4;
var nodes = Y.all(".box"+ number);

nodes.each(function(node){  

    node.addClass(number);

});
```

Thanks a million!

Comment: You're re-declaring `number` and `nodes` everytime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
var numbers = [2, 3, 4];

for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
  var boxnum = numbers[i];
  Y.all(".box"+boxnum ).addClass(boxnum);  
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/854Th/

Comment: cheers Dan, that seems like it should work, but it does nothing for me!

Comment: sorry see my edit, i'm not so familiar with YUI, i had this working in jsfiddle though!

Comment: thanks Dan, that workd beautifully. thanks for the fiddle too!

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do `each`. Just use addClass function on `Y.all(...)`. Like this...

```
var arr = [2, 3, 4];
var query = ".box" + arr.join(", .box");
Y.all(query).addClass(levelnumber);
```

Comment: thanks mohkan, but then how do I declare the value of the variable 'number'? how does it know to do that fucntion for all values of number 2 to 4?

Comment: thanks alot mohkan, i will need this bit of code in future. wish i could mark more than one answer correct on here :(